# Allow adding of Gitlab projects to SO profile

Tags: feature-request, user-accounts

We can already have GitHub and BitBucket projects linked to our SO accounts, but a lot of us use Gitlab, and it would be good to also have the option of adding Gitlab repos to our accounts.

Comment: Worth to mention, SE itself [are using GitLab](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/which-tools-and-technologies-are-used-to-build-the-stack-exchange-network/10370#10370).

Comment: Good idea! Especially, the "Web presence" section in profile shows only GitHub field.